# C++ Winsocks, recv(socket,512,0) only receiving one char at a time

Tags: c++, winsock

For some weird reason, I initialize the sockets:

```
void init()
{
    cout << "\t\t-----TCP SERVER---" << endl;
    cout << endl;

    //STEP 1 WSAStartup
    iwsastartup = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &Winsockdata);
    if (iwsastartup != 0){
        cout << "startup failed" << endl;
    }
    cout << "startup success" << endl;
    //STEP 2 fill structure
    TCPServerAdd.sin_family = AF_INET;
    TCPServerAdd.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    TCPServerAdd.sin_port = htons(8000);

    //STEP 3 socket creation
    TCPServerSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (TCPServerSocket == INVALID_SOCKET){
        cout << "server socket creation failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    }
    //STEP 4 binding
    iBind = ::bind(TCPServerSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&TCPServerAdd, sizeof(TCPServerAdd));
    if (iBind == SOCKET_ERROR){
        cout << "Binding failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    }
    cout << "binding success" << endl;
    iListen = listen(TCPServerSocket, 2);
    //STEP 5 listening
    if (iListen == SOCKET_ERROR){
        cout << "listening failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    }
    cout << "listening..." << endl;
    //STEP 6 accept
    sAcceptSocket = accept(TCPServerSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&TCPClientAdd, &iTCPClientAdd);
    if (sAcceptSocket == INVALID_SOCKET){
        cout << "accept failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
    }
    cout << "connection accepted" << endl;
}
```

Where Send and Recv buffers are const char[512], and recieve and send like so:

```
void recieve_(){
    while (true)
    {

        //STEP 7 recv data from client
        iRecv = recv(sAcceptSocket, RecvBuffer, iRecvBuffer, 0);
        if (iRecv == SOCKET_ERROR){
            cout << "recv failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        }
        else{
            //cout << "recv:" << RecvBuffer << endl;
            MessageBox(nullptr, LPCWSTR(RecvBuffer), TEXT("Message"), MB_OK);
        }
    }
}
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    init();
    //STEP 7 send data to client

    thread t1(recieve_);

    while (true){
        system("PAUSE");
        iSend = send(sAcceptSocket, SenderBuffer, iSenderBuffer, 0);
        if (iSend == SOCKET_ERROR){
            cout << "sending failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        }
        else{
            cout << "sent successfully" << endl;
        }
    }
    //STEP 9 close socket
    iCloseSocket = closesocket(TCPServerSocket);
    closesocket(sAcceptSocket);
    WSACleanup();
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Even in a simpler, single threaded version, the buffer is just the first charcter of the sent buffer, eg
char SendBuffer[512] = "Hello";
is recieved as a 512 array with only element 0 set, is this a configuration issue?

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `LPCWSTR(RecvBuffer)` doesn't make sense if RecvBuffer contains `char`.  Print `iRecv` to see how many bytes you received.

Comment: iRecv is 1, even when I hardcode 512 or 513 in the sending param

Comment: What is `iRecvBuffer` ? Here you should pass `sizeof(RecvBuffer)`, but I suspect you are passing `1`.

Comment: Or in other words, put a breakpoint on that line, then inspect the values of the variables. Use the debugger.

Comment: I have, send buffer is filled char by char fully, recv buff is the first element, then just \0 for the other 511, iRecv is 1, no errors with any of the sockets

Comment: Even if I put recv() in a while(total_bytes < 512) the issues persists.

Comment: nevermind iSend was 1, thanks